# FFmpeg wrapper for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-ffmpeg

I succeed to compile ffmpeg and to get `.so` files for different arch such as amreabi, armeabi-v7a, etc.

I managed to integrate these pre-built libraries to my android project using `CMakeLists.txt` through own `.cpp` wrapper. The problem is I have no skills in C++. So  another way to use `ffmpeg` is to make a call `main()` function of `ffmpeg.c`. [This](https://medium.com/madhavanmalolan/ffmpeg-for-android-b307f2613c82) link describes the steps how to do that.

In my project:

> structure

[image: Structure]

> Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```

> Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
#$(warning $(LOCAL_PATH))

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libffmpeg
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -landroid
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wdeprecated-declarations
ANDROID_LIB := -landroid
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=./ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  ffmpeg_controller.c ffmpeg.c ffmpeg_filter.c ffmpeg_opt.c cmdutils.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil libswresample libavfilter libavdevice

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-add-path,D:/My-Project/app/src/main/jni)
$(call import-module,ffmpeg/android/armeabi-v7a)
```

> ffmpeg/android/armeabi-v7a/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavdevice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavdevice-57.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavcodec-57.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavformat-57.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libswscale-4.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavutil-55.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavfilter-6.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libswresample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libswresample-2.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

> build.gradle

```
...
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
    }
...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/x86/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/x86_64/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/*.so"
    }
...
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = ["jni"] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    lintOptions {
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
        warning 'MissingPermission'
        warning 'MissingConstraints'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
```

After the build project it gives many errors in `ffmpeg/*.c`, `ffmpeg/*.h` files and in `jni/ffmpeg.c`, `jni/cmdutils.c`, ect. The errors are like *"config.h not found"*, *"libavformat/os_support.h not found"*. If I add the `config.h` file to the `jni/` folder from `ffmpeg/` and replace `libavformat/os_support.h` with `ffmpeg/libavformat/os_support.h` then the errors are gone, but `.c` syntax errors still there. According to the tutorial I mustn't do such changes in sources and all should be ok.

What did I do wrong? How else I can use ffmpeg command line tool in Android Project?

*Android NDK version - 13b,
FFmpeg version - 3.0.12*

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that a wrapper is the easiest way to approach ffmpeg on Android - similar to the approach you are taking.

I did manage to build and get running an ffmpeg wrapper but found quite a few issues along the way and only targeted the particular system architecture I was working on at the time.

If I was doing it again (or even if had had to do it 5 mins after I finished originally...) I would definitely use a well supported and commonly used opensource wrapper. Two of the most popular are:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java (for Android)
- https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg (iOS and Android)

These will usually have already addressed the issues you would have to find and fix yourself otherwise and also can support multiple system architectures.